# Stubbing defaults in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, stubbing

How can I stub a method such that when given a value I'm not expecting, it returns a default value?

For example:

```
Map<String, String> map = mock(Map.class);
when(map.get("abcd")).thenReturn("defg");
when(map.get("defg")).thenReturn("ghij");
when(map.get(anyString())).thenReturn("I don't know that string");
```

Part 2: As above but throws an exception:

```
Map<String, String> map = mock(Map.class);
when(map.get("abcd")).thenReturn("defg");
when(map.get("defg")).thenReturn("ghij");
when(map.get(anyString())).thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException("I don't know that string"));
```

In the above examples, the last stub takes precedence so the map will always return the default.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The best solution I have found is to reverse the order of the stubs:

```
Map<String, String> map = mock(Map.class);
when(map.get(anyString())).thenReturn("I don't know that string");
when(map.get("abcd")).thenReturn("defg");
when(map.get("defg")).thenReturn("ghij");
```

When the default is to throw an exception you can just use doThrow and doReturn

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(map).get(anyString());
doReturn("defg").when(map).get("abcd");
doReturn("ghij").when(map).get("defg");
```

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer including `doReturn()`. (`doThrow()` is unnecessary in this case except for consistency.)

Comment: The stub ordering thing is called out in the same documentation you referenced there: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12 — "Last stubbing is more important - when you stubbed the same method with the same arguments many times."

Answer (score 3):

```
when(map.get(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
    public String answer(Invocation invocation) {
        String arg = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        if (args.equals("abcd")
             return "defg";
        // etc.
        else
             return "default";
             // or throw new Exception()
    }
});
```

It's kind of a roundabout way to do this. But it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Map<String, String> map = mock(Map.class, new Returns("I don't know that string"));
when(map.get("abcd")).thenReturn("defg");
when(map.get("defg")).thenReturn("ghij");
```